# OneHotEncoding changes numerical attributes to nan

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a beginner and I have a dataset with categories with no order so I want to use OneHotEncoding to change them to numerical values for my Isolation Forest.
I wrote a function that takes a dataframe (and specific columns if wanted, otherwise it uses all object columns), uses a OneHotEncoder for each categorical column with the .fit_transform() method, adds the values to the dataframe, changes the column names and then deletes the actual object column.

Here is my function:

```
def ohe(dataframe, cat_cols=None):
    
    df = dataframe.copy()
    
    if cat_cols==None:
        cat_cols= df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).columns
    
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    
    #OneHotEncoding for every single column
    for col in cat_cols:
        new_cols = encoder.fit_transform(df[col].values.reshape(-1,1))
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_cols.astype("int"))], axis=1) #add new columns to the DataFrame
        
        #replace the new column names 
        new_col_order = encoder.categories_[0].tolist() #List of the categories in order of the columns
        number_new_col = len(new_col_order) #number of new columns added
        
        colnames = {}
        for i in range(0, number_new_col):
            colnames[int(df.iloc[:, -len(new_col_order)::].columns[i])] = str(col) + "_" + str(new_col_order[i]) #dict with key=old_column_name, value=new_column_name
        
        df.rename(columns=colnames, inplace=True)
        
        #drop the not-encoded column
        df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    return df
```

I used it on a small, manually created dataset and it works fine but when I use it on the actual data, I mostly get NaNs for all the numeric attributes. I don't do anything with them in the function so why are they changed?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it can help to see what code is doing.

Comment: You should provide a dataset that demonstrates the problem, part of a minimal reproducible example.
One likely culprit: does your dataframe have an index other than the default one?
The slickest solution is probably to use a `ColumnTransformer`.

Comment: @GoldenLion I read on stackoverflow that one should use OneHotEncoder for machine learning purposes

Comment: @furas I will try this out, hopefully it will help me to understand what's going on! Thanks!

Comment: @BenReiniger it is corporate data so I sadly cannot show how it looks.